# C#.Net List<T> in Grid View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, gridview, collections

This might be a simple question, I have a List of strings which contain information about movies. I also have a grid view of which I have binded the list of strings to as the datasource. In the image i have attached, I have created the column headers for each of the fields. (Title, Description, AgeRating, Price).

The problem is each item in my list stores an entire movie reference.
E.g: `[0]"Interstellar;Sci-Fi Film;12;4.00"` I have attached an image of the list of strings so you understand what I mean.

How can I make it so that each item is broken down into 'title', 'Description' 'ageRating' and 'price' so that they fall under the neccessary columns

e.g: Title: Interstellar
     Description: Space Stuff
     AgeRating: 12
     Price: 5.00

[image: Movie Data Grid Image]
[image: List of Strings]

```
List<string> movie = MovieM.listMovies();


        if (movie != null)
        {

            GVmovies.DataSource = movie;
            GVmovies.DataBind();
            GVmovies.BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
            GVmovies.BorderColor = Color.DarkGreen;�
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list of strings, I would create a custom object for your movie:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Set your properties for each movie and then bind a collection of these objects instead of the list of strings.

Comment: would there be no way to do it just using a list of strings?

Comment: @J.Proud I'm not aware of a way to do that with binding. You would have to split the strings on the semicolon and manually add the rows.